# How to iterate json object through ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

I am trying to iterate success data in ajax response to show in jQuery dialog, but unable to do that.

Here is my controller where I am trying to iterate:

```
function fnMicEdit(){     
    var value=$( 'input[name=check]:checked' ).val();
    alert(value);
       $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:'getMicPopupData.htm',
        data: 'radiovalue='+value,
        success : function(data) {
            $("#popup").val(data);

            //how to iterate object in here to show all the data into textbox
            // table column and value is unknown to me so, I fetched column and value using metadata
            //now how to show in the jQuery dialog

        },
        error:function(){
          alert('error');
        }
        });
    }
```

From controller getting this format of data, I have no idea how to iterate this format to get key as "MODULE" and value as "VERSION_UPGRADE" of that key.

```js
[{
  MODULE = VERSION_UPGRADE,
  IKEA_VERSION_NO = 18.2 .0,
  UNIFY_VERSION_NO = 18.2 .0,
  MOC = 04 - 2018,
  START_DATE = 2018 - 03 - 23,
  END_DATE = 2018 - 03 - 24,
  START_DAY = ,
  END_DAY =
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate through data first as it is an array. Then you can iterate through the object. Below is the code :

```
data.forEach(function(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            console.log(key + " : " + obj[key]);
        }
    }
});
```

If you have any questions you can ask.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I am getting error while debug this code "Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'".

Comment: I want to iterate such a way that "MODULE" should be key and "VERSION_UPGRADE" should be value of that key.

Comment: It did it using two for loop here is my code         $.each(data, function (index, element) {
                 $.each(element, function (key,value) {
                  console.log(key+":"+value);
                 
                   $("#popup").append("<p style='display:inline'>"+key+":"+"<input type='text' name="+key+" id="+key+" value=\""+value+"\" class='size-box' /></p>");
                 });
               });